# How do I represent the probability of a particular die roll in formal notation?

Tags: probability, notation

I'm trying to represent the projected outcome of a series of die rolls in a formal, nice-looking notation.

The die rolls go as follows:

1. Roll a two-sided die twice and then add two to the sum of the output. This represents the number of objects generated.
2. For each generated object, roll a two-sided die to determine the value of each object.
3. The total output is the sum of values.

I've made a table of what the probability of different outcomes would be, but I want to include a title over the graph and I'm not familiar with probability notation and don't know how to represent what I have.

```
P(?) = (2d2 + 2)d2
```

How do I represent the right-hand-side of the equation in formal probability notation?

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't.  Using words and explaining like you did here will be far more easily readable given how convoluted it is.

Comment: You could do this with a generating function like thingie, like $\left(\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)^2
\left[\frac{\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{2}}{2} + \frac{\left(\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)^2}{2} \right]^2$, but golly, that's a mess. I'm with @JMoravitz, it's much clearer in plain English (or whatever natural language). (ETA: I definitely screwed up the old one, and I might still have screwed up this one, but I think it makes its point either way—this ain't the way to go!)

Comment: I'd be curious what they would say on the Role-Playing Games Stack Exchange, as to whether this notation is clear or not....

Comment: @Paul: That's a good question. I certainly would have guessed correctly, but I don't know how generally true that is.

Answer (score 2):

What you've defined is a "[random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable)".

The usual notation for one is an upper-case italic, like $X$, $Y$, or $X_i$ if you've got multiple ones. If there is a meaningful name for the quantity, like say "stealth", then $X_{stealth}$ might be used.

A discrete random variable like this is usually presented in a table like this (which it sounds like you've already got):

\begin{array}
{|r|r:r:r:r:r|l|} \hline X_{foo} & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\hdashline \mathsf P(X_{foo}=x) & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.3 \\ \hline
\end{array}

(I assume your random variable can assume many more values than this example, so you would probably use two columns instead of two rows. That's fine, this was just the first snippet of LaTeX code I found.)

As for the title, the (standard?) dice notation runs a bit contrary to standard random variable notation. When you write "2d6" you mean rolling two separate dice, but $2X_{d6}$ would mean roll one and double the value generated - "$X_1 + X_2$, where $X_i \sim d6$" would be appropriate random variable notation.

I'd say, since you're already assuming familiarity with dice notation, that you stick with it, and a title mostly like what you already have would work fine:

$$X_{foo} = (2d2 + 2)\cdot d2$$

The fact that you're using dice rolls to determine how many dice to roll in the second stage feels a little non-standard to me, so hopefully you'd have already explained your procedure before presenting the table. But with that done I think your notation is clear.

(If you want the fully math-y way to write this out, I could provide it, but I think it'd actually just be confusing in your case. If you're already using the "2d6" notation, why get pedantic at this stage?)

Comment: I'm curious, what did you have in mind for your fully math-y way to write it out?

Comment: As for the standardness of the notation, it *is* standard within tabletop gaming.  The $d$ can be thought of as acting as an operator.  Given whole numbers $x,y$ we have the notation $x d y$ is the random variable equal to the sum of $x$ i.i.d. uniform random variables over the set $\{1,2,\dots,y\}$, and you can have $x,y$ themselves be expressions or random variables too.  The $d$ operator is given higher priority in the order of operations than multiplication/division (*but parentheses can certainly help avoid ambiguity*).  See any D&D or Warhammer rulebook or the like.

Comment: Like other random variables, it can be further modified by using it in a function such as adding to the final result or squaring, etc... It is traditional that $y$ specifically be one of $\{2,3,4,6,8,10,12,20,30,100\}$, being the most common number of sides to be found on dice, but nothing technically stops it from being something else.

Comment: @BrianTung - Something like $$X_{foo} = \sum_{i=1}^{X_1 + X_2 + 2} Y_i,$$ where $X_1, X_2, Y_i \sim d6$, I guess. Like I said, it doesn't add much. The fact that you have to "instantiate a new r.v." for each new die makes it a pain.

Comment: @JMoravitz - I'm used to seeing stuff like "$x$d$y$", but I hadn't seen an expression like that being used as the dice count before. How common is that - i.e. would most players have seen it before, or would most players require an explanation?